# FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable join conditions

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two Redshift tables which get joined on an id and a date in a specific date range.

When I try to full-outer-join the tables (both alternative SQL statements further down below), I get the following error:

```
[Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: FULL JOIN is only supported with merge-joinable join conditions; [SQL State=0A000, DB Errorcode=500310]
```

It works for LEFT-JOIN, but not for FULL-OUTER. I basically want to have all ids and ranges in there, even if there were no matches in the other table.
How can I solve this error?

Table 1:

- id
- colx (date)

Table 2:

- id
- col2 (date range beginning)
- col3 (date range end)
- something

First alternative join:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2
      ON (table1.id = ltrim(table2.id, '0') -- id
      AND DATE(table1.colx) BETWEEN DATE(table2.col2) AND DATE(table2.col3) -- date range
      )  
 ;
```

Second alternative join:  (according to the AWS documentation, the range is inclusive, so the statements should have the same results I suppose)

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 
  FULL OUTER JOIN table2
      ON table1.id = ltrim(table2.id, '0') -- id
      AND DATE(table1.colx) >= table2.col2  -- date range beginning
      AND DATE(table1.colx) <= table2.col3  -- date range ending
;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Does rewriting it using `union all` fix the problem?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.id = ltrim(t2.id, '0') AND 
        DATE(t1.colx) BETWEEN DATE(t2.col2) AND DATE(t2.col3)
UNION ALL
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table2 t2 LEFT JOIN
     table1 t1
     ON t1.id = ltrim(t2.id, '0') AND
        DATE(t1.colx) BETWEEN DATE(t2.col2) AND DATE(t2.col3)
WHERE t1.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Wouldn't I get duplicate rows for all rows which exist on both sides from the 'UNION ALL' ? Doing a "SELECT DISTINCT FROM () " around it might solve it, but it is rather ugly...

Comment: @Cribber . . . No.  The first subquery returns all rows in `t1` whether or not there are matching rows in `t2`.  The second returns only the rows in `t2` that have no match in `t1`.